# How to do ordered DELETE?

Tags: postgresql

How do you delete rows forcing a sequential delete of each row in certain order?

For example, to delete rows in a blockchain table I must delete from last row to the first row, for example:

```
DELETE FROM block WHERE block_num IN (
    SELECT block_num
    FROM block
    WHERE block_num > $1
    ORDER BY block_num DESC
)
```

but Postgres docs do not say about order of 'DELETE's , and if the 'DELETE's aren't executed in an orderly fashion, my triggers will create invalid statistical data. So, how do I enforce order of deletion?

Comment: Looks like a problem in your trigger, not the delete. When a trigger depends on a set of data, you need a statement trigger and not a row level trigger

Comment: @FrankHeikens not in my case, since each row has different update function, statement trigger would not be useful

Comment: Then you have to delete the records one by one, using multiple statements.

Comment: Post your table definition(s), the trigger in question and sample data that that demonstrates the required order. Also what version of Postgres are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank Heikens explained and demonstrated [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f5db8fef63e91ef99221bbf94f0539d9), the cte solution here below guarantees the right order in the select statement but not in the deletion statement :

```
WITH list AS
(
    SELECT block_num
    FROM block
    WHERE block_num > $1
    ORDER BY block_num DESC
)
DELETE FROM block AS b
USING list As l
WHERE b.block_num  =  l.block_num ;
```

So a more accurate solution can be a loop in a plpgsql procedure, assuming that `block_num`  is of type integer :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deletion_block_num (min integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    i integer ;
BEGIN
FOR i IN
    SELECT block_num
      FROM block
     WHERE block_num > $1
     ORDER BY block_num DESC
LOOP
    DELETE FROM block AS b
    WHERE b.block_num  =  i ;
END LOOP ;
END ;
$$

CALL deletion_block_num (1) ;
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the delete will be executed in the order of the list. The list is ordered, but that’s it

Comment: When making tests with `RAISE NOTICE  '%', block_num ` included in a function executed for each row before delete on `block`, we can see that the deletion order conforms the list order. No guarantee, but what could influence postgres in making it in a different order ?

Comment: How the data is stored on disk. Try this Fiddle a couple of times and you will see that the output is not always in the order you would like to see. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f5db8fef63e91ef99221bbf94f0539d9

Comment: ok clear, thanks for the demo.